# Say go team in Chinese?

Tags: mandarin, word-choice

Normally I would say 加油. On my city's news page this morning, they asked 10 people how to say "Go Syracuse (雪城)". There's a video of two men debating what to say, and then they say something like 雪城 __. I'm not sure what the other 2 words are. BiXue?

Can anyone tell me what the characters are?

Is this something more popular in China? In Taiwan, I always used 加油.

Here's the link (it's in the middle and right at the end):
http://www.syracuse.com/news/index.ssf/2014/03/what_does_lets_go_orange_sound_like_in_10_different_languages.html#incart_river_default

Comment: It is "雪城 **必胜**!" Literally translate, "Syracuse will definitely win!"

Comment: Thanks! I guess they changed up the meaning a little bit. Any idea about the use of the phrase in Taiwan vs. China? Is that phrase a little less modern?

Comment: Both "XX加油" and "XX必胜(必勝 in Traditional Chinese)" are commonly used in mainland and Taiwan for a general "go team" phrase nowadays. The minor difference in meaning doesn't change the same function of them. And you can even find "必勝(ひっしょう)" is used in Japan.

Comment: 必胜 is usually used for a match, and 加油 can be used in wider range to encourage someone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At Chinese mainland, we use 必胜 or 加油, they are both OK.

And, no, there are no phrase more popular than those two phrases, at least in my experience.